# NPM run dev not compiling assets with error notifications for user are disabled on Windows 10

Tags: vue.js, npm

I recently reinstalled the Windows 10 operating system,

Upon running `npm-install command`, npm installs correctly. However, on running the `npm-run watch` command or `npm run-dev` command, assets are not been compiled.

The following message is been displayed:

> Notifications are disabled Reason: DisabledForUserPlease make sure that the app id is set correctly.

I have tried to reinstall and install Laravel 7, but the same issue persists. OS: Windows 10 build version 10240.

#### Screenshot of the message after running npm-run watch on CMD

[image: Screenshot of the message after running npm-run watch on CMD]

#### Windows Notifications settings

[image: Windows Notifications settings]

Answer (score 15):

All you have to do is Enable windows notification:

*Windows settings* → *Notifications & actions* (on Windows 10)

And finally:

```
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 4):

add `mix.disableNotifications()` to the webpack.mis.js file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the file name is webpack.mix.js not mis.js

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I muted the notification from snoretoast-x64.exe (see your screenshot of the error) in the windows action center after running a watch.

I just had to enable notification from SnoreToast again in *Windows settings* → *Notifications & actions* (on Windows 10).

It went back to normal after that :)

Answer (score 0):

u should run the command

```
npx mix
```

it will even install the required dependencies like 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass' and 'sass-loader' the u can compile the assets u want. Here is the documentation , it is very simple explanation [mix documentation](https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/what-is-mix.md) .
then u can run

```
npx mix watch
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because your snoretoast notifications are disables. Go to you **windows settings** -> **notifications and actions** scroll down and enable the snoretoast notifications. please refer to the attached screenshot

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etwp8.png)