# I got a error while running npm run watch in laravel and vuejs project

Tags: laravel, vue.js

The toast encountered an error.
error is -

```
Please make sure that the app id is set correctly.
```

Command is :

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\vue js\inventry_management_system\node_modules\no
de-notifier\vendor\snoreToast\snoretoast-x64.exe" -appID "Laravel Mix" -pipeName
 \\.\pipe\notifierPipe-5883adc4-fd1a-4d36-91af-d6c8e49a72a5 -p "D:\xampp\htdocs\
vue js\inventry_management_system\node_modules\laravel-mix\icons\laravel.png" -m
 "Build successful" -t "Laravel Mix
```

Comment: Did you try looking at this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64949275/npm-run-dev-not-compiling-assets-with-error-notifications-for-user-are-disabled